# SQL Having Count(*)

Tags: sql, count, having

I have this table :

```
Code       Nom           Prenom
192        Potter        Harry
192        Granger       Hermione
197        Malfoy        Drago
```

I need to have a result likt that :

```
Code       Nom           Prenom     count
192        Potter        Harry      2
192        Granger       Hermione   2
197        Malfoy        Drago      1
```

I try with having, but i can't with 'Nom' and 'Prenom' only the count. Have you a solution ? Thanks

Comment: What SQL have you tried? Which DBMS is this?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    Code,
    Nom,
    Prenom,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code) AS MyCount
FROM
    MyTable
```

Comment: While this may provide the solution to this specific problem, it's highly encouraged for answers to explain the general solution (e.g. a couple of sentences explaining the concept of "window functions"), rather than just including code. This helps both the poster of this question, and future readers, understand how to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: @IMSoP It's also highly encouraged to edit and improve answers, which you are more than welcome to do.

Comment: Or, I could write my own answer; or downvote yours. I chose instead to suggest how you can improve this and future contributions to the site. Whether you choose to act on that suggestion is up to you.

Comment: oh it's ok, really thanks ! With this method, it's possible to filter only > 2 ?

Comment: @Manolel You could make this a sub query. Then the outer query could have a `WHERE` clause stating `MyCount > 2`